# Set function results as a variable

Tags: php, wordpress, function, variables

I'm using this code to get all author first names that have posted in the current category:

```
function categoryAuthors() {
    $category_authors = array();
    $args = array(
        'posts_per_page'     => -1,
        'category'           => $category,
        'post_status'        => 'publish'
    );
    $allposts = get_posts($args);
    if ($allposts) {
        foreach($allposts as $authorpost) {
            $category_authors[$authorpost->post_author]+=1;
        }
        arsort($category_authors);
        foreach($category_authors as $key => $author_post_count) {
            $user = get_userdata($key);
            $an_author = "'" . $user->first_name . "', ";
            echo $an_author;
        }
    }
}


$theAuthors = categoryAuthors();
echo $theAuthors;
```

..which almost works, but, if I comment out the echo like this...

```
// echo $theAuthors;
```

... all the email addresses are echoed on my page regardless.

My understanding is that a function won't be called until you actually call it, but it seems to be called (outputting on the page) anyway even if I don't echo $theAuthors.

Anyway, I am trying to make a variable that is a comma separated list of the author first names, so that I can use it in other places.

How can I fix this?

Cheers.

Comment: Your function needs to _return_ something!

Comment: What? You are invoking the function when you use the `()` operator. Furthermore, you are echoing the `$an_author` variable in the function body.

Comment: Do you understand that `echo` is the same as `print`, right?

Comment: instead of print return `$an_author`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> use **return()** into function

```
function categoryAuthors() {
     $an_author = '';
    $category_authors = array();
    $args = array(
        'posts_per_page'     => -1,
        'category'           => $category,
        'post_status'        => 'publish'
    );
    $allposts = get_posts($args);
    if ($allposts) {
        foreach($allposts as $authorpost) {
            $category_authors[$authorpost->post_author]+=1;
        }
        arsort($category_authors);
        foreach($category_authors as $key => $author_post_count) {
            $user = get_userdata($key);
            $an_author .= "'" . $user->first_name . "', ";
        }
    }
    return $an_author;
}


$theAuthors = categoryAuthors();
echo $theAuthors;
```

Comment: It should also be noted that he's using a string concatenation (which is what `.=` is) so you get one complete string

Comment: Where is `$category` coming from in the `$args` array? This function still isn't going to work.

Comment: @jszobody That's not completely fair, the OP has made it clear that the function works when echoing out the data so the changes in this answer would make it work...

Comment: @jeroen I suppose. We're clearly dealing with a PHP beginner here, I'd argue a good answer should attempt to help the OP understand this code issue as well.

Answer (score 0):

You have no return statement in your function thats why when you call the function no variable is returned. However you have an echo statement so that means when you call the function it just prints all the names.

To fix this remove the line that echoes the string in each for each loop iteration and instead build a string with all the names and then return it at the end of the function.

Example:

```
<?php
 function categoryAuthors() {
    $category_authors = array();
    $names = '';
    $args = array(
        'posts_per_page'     => -1,
        'category'           => $category,
        'post_status'        => 'publish'
    );
    $allposts = get_posts($args);
    if ($allposts) {
        foreach($allposts as $authorpost) {
            $category_authors[$authorpost->post_author]+=1;
        }
        arsort($category_authors);
        foreach($category_authors as $key => $author_post_count) {
            $user = get_userdata($key);
            $an_author = "'" . $user->first_name . "', ";
            //echo $an_author;
            $names = "$names, $an_author";
        }
    }
    return $names;
}


$theAuthors = categoryAuthors();
echo $theAuthors;
?>
```

Comment: Have a look now ;)